# How can I make a custom MSBuild Target's execution dependent on a file's time stamp?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

The C++ project I'm working on (which I converted from VS2008 to VS2010) used to use several vcbuild .rules files to specify custom build rules. These .rules files had a specific "AdditionalDependencies" property for the CustomBuildRule node which specified a list of files that the should be taken into account when working out if the target needs rebuilding or not. These "AdditionalDependencies" were faithfully carried over into the corresponding .props file during the VS2010 conversion.

The .targets file associated with the custom build rule does add these `AdditionalDependencies` to the `Inputs` property of the `Target` node. This ensures that the target gets executed in case any of the files listed in the dependencies doesn't exist, but it does not execute the target if one of the dependencies is newer than the target's output. It's also not quite logically correct as not all of the files are actually inputs, several of them refer to executables that might be used during the target's build. As such, they might be checked into version control and will be present, but a newer version of the file needs to trigger a rebuild of the affected target.

The [MSDN documentation for the Target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx) node shows a `Condition` property which should work fine for my requirements, but the conditions supported by this property don't appear go past the 'Exists' test that is already being performed.

Is there a condition that I can use which will compare two files' time stamps (or ideally, the time stamp of the files currently listed in `AdditionalDependencies` against the Target's output files) and thus allow me to trigger a make-like "rebuild this target if it is out of date these dependencies"?

Answer (score 3):

Please take a closer look to the target `Output` property:

*"MSBuild can compare the timestamps of the input files with the timestamps of the output files and determine whether to skip, build, or partially rebuild a target. In the following example, if any file in the @(CSFile) item list is newer than the hello.exe file, MSBuild will run the target; otherwise it will be skipped:"*

```
<Target Name="Build" 
    Inputs="@(CSFile)" 
    Outputs="hello.exe">

    <Csc
        Sources="@(CSFile)" 
        OutputAssembly="hello.exe"/>
</Target>
```

The original article and more information about incremental builds with MSBuild can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171483.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the Inputs vs Outputs properties for the target. The problem is that even if the Inputs property contains the name of the 'generator' executable and the timestamp changes, the Outputs aren't necessarily regenerated.

Comment: Perhaps the "name of the generator executable" in the input property does not represent a path to the file, and as a result MSBuild is not able to discover the changed timestamp.